# What man-in-the-middle apps crash internet capabilities in some apps?

Tags: android, packet-capture, man-in-the-middle

I've tested some man-in-the-middle apps (traffic packet capture) in Android, and in some apps works very well, but in others it disables internet capabilities in the app and the app stop to work (and appears the typical messages of "Network unavailable").

Why is that ?

Is there any other way to capture the internet calls an app does ?

I've tried with adb logcat, but not all apps "writes" there everything :-P

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze network traffic you can try using Charles Proxy and rerouting the traffic from the internet -> Charles on a PC/MAC/LINUX -> Mobile app. Beware that since most mobile apps use HTTPS you will also need to install the Charles certificate onto the mobile device to be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic.